# Windows 11 console closing early compared to Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, python, windows-11, console

I have a Python program that starts other programs using subprocess.Popen, and then generally exits.  On Windows 10, this works fine: The console created by the Python program is used for the other programs until all programs are complete.  This seems to be as documented [here at Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/closing-a-console?redirectedfrom=MSDN). The relevant quotation being:

> A console is closed when the last process attached to it terminates or calls FreeConsole.

A couple of my users using Windows 11 reported that running my program creates the console, but then the console disappears in a flash.  After pondering this a while, I added a five-minute delay to my program using atexit.register, and the result on Windows 11 was that the program it launched ran successfully.... but was terminated after 5 minutes when the console window went away.

Is this a change in behavior between Windows 10 and 11?  Is it a bug?  Is there a workaround?

Based on the comments received, maybe the change in behavior isn't due to the console getting closed early, but the child process getting terminated when the parent terminates.  Either way, though, there is a definite, incompatible difference in behavior between Windows 10 and 11, and I'd sure like to know the cause.

After more searching regarding the Windows console, I discovered that the default for console programs is now Windows Terminal (Win 11 22H2). Could Windows Terminal have a different default behavior in this regard than Windows Console?  All the pages I find about Windows Terminal tout the visible differences, but don't address this detail.

Answer (score 1):

It might be a difference is scheduling : If there is even one second
in which the console has no users, then it should be closed.
This is true for both Windows 10 and 11, but Windows 10 might be slower
about closing the console.

You should therefore not free the console before some other process has
connected to it.

If the above is not possible, you should change your program so it will
not detach itself after creating the console. You could add perhaps a
"Stop" button or a prompt for "Press Enter to terminate",
as the case may be.

Comment: Interesting thought, but after I added the 5-minute delay in the parent program, there would be no possibility of 0 users of the console... at the end of the 5 minutes, the parent died, so did the console window, and so did the child program (which also had opened other windows).

Comment: The termination of the parent does not normally cause the termination of its children. In effect, the terminated parent stays on as a zombie process until all its children terminate.

Comment: Regarding termination, that's certainly my understanding, except I don't know anything about the parent staying around as a zombie (on Windows).  But my users definitely report that after my added 5-minute timeout in the parent, the console disappears, and the child process disappears.  This doesn't happen on Windows 10, as stated, but on Windows 11 it does.  So whether the effect is happening because the console is closed when the parent dies (my assumption), or because the children are terminated when the parent dies (a new thought based on your comment), Win 10 and 11 act differently.

Comment: Updated question to speculate about Windows Terminal

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is probably solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75539108/whats-change-with-detach-of-process-on-windows-11-compared-with-windows-10-from)

Long story short.
This parameter in popen call

```
creationflags=subprocess.DETACHED_PROCESS
```

Should solve your problem.

Comment: That's an interesting idea, and I learned a few things by reading the pages link from your link, and searching some documentation.  But: I'm using the same version of Python to launch the program with subprocess.Popen, not passing the DETACHED_PROCESS flag (or any flag) to Popen, and getting different behaviors on Win 10 and Win 11. So I don't think DETACHED_PROCESS can be the cause, unless Win11 changed the default when flags are not supplied, to be different than the historic default of not setting it. Further, I want the child process to use the same console window as the parent.

Comment: I am the same person there and here. I didn't use the DETACHED_PROCESS flag too. But I had to use it to make the process continue after the death of the parent process on Windows 11. What parameters are you using to start children's processes?

Comment: Basically I am using default parameters.  But unlike you, I want the launched console program to continue using the same console window as the launching console program.  DETACHED_PROCESS doesn't _seem_ to allow for that.  On the other hand, I guess it would be OK to have the launching console progrem have a different console window, since it will go away quickly.  But does the launched console program, if launched with DETACHED_PROCESS, get a console window at all?

Comment: And of course, why the change?